# Spring MVC - code based servlet container initialization

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlets, web.xml

I am a newbie and going through spring learning curve and i have a question to understand what cases i will be using code based servlet container initialization against xml initialization in web descriptor file.

The reason for my question is, at this time i wanted to spend time in learning what is used most of the time rather overloading many concepts which might be provided with the framework just for flexibility.

Any advice?
Thanks for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason you'd want to use Java based container initialization is when you want to register Spring managed `Servlet`, `Filter`, and `XxxListener` objects.

For example, when you want to register a `ServletContextListener`, you specify

```
<listener>
    com.your.listeners.MyListener
</listener>
```

in the deployment descriptor. The container takes that fully qualified class name and uses reflection to find the corresponding `Class` object which it instantiates to get an instance. In other words, the object is uniquely managed by the container. You can't have Spring inject fields easily.

On the other hand, with a `ServletContainerInitializer`, or the corresponding Spring class, you can specify `Servlet`, `Filter`, or `Listener` beans in your Spring context (either through XML or `@Configuration` classes) and register those Spring-managed instances directly through the `ServletContext`.

---

Note that there are still some configurations for which you need to use the deployment descriptor.